# Will Paginate: How change default page in links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have two partial. The first have a common will_paginate but in the second will_paginate I need to change the links (default url) generated by will_paginate.

Please I need their answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
will_paginate(@some_collection, :params => { :controller => "foo", :action => "bar" })
```

Comment: @xlubyonrails  
I tried but will_paginate don´t change the link

Comment: Ok as I understand you have two partials and you want the WP links to work as regular links in the first and in the second partial to work with AJAX right?

Comment: @xlubyonrails excuse m I am working. In dact, the two partial are using ajax. the first use the new action but when the user selected product from a list (ajax request where refind new paginated product collection. I render partial with new will_paginate helper but this must contain new link to ajax action)

Comment: If your links at the second time you render via xhr, are not working then you have to use the .live() jQuery function which let you bind the click event to a DOM element that it is not present yet. Have you tried this? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @xlubyonrails yes, i am using jQuery. However the links fail because the href = new action. I want href = ajax action in link will_paginate

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:param_name` to change the query-string parameter:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :param_name => :posts_page %> 
<%= will_paginate @comments, :param_name => :comments_page %>
```

Note that in your controller you must also change this:

```
@posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:posts_page] 
@comments = Comment.paginate :page => params[:comments_page]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to change the links in page. however your answer is good data.